# Android AOSP master build fail! FAILED: out/soong/.primary/soong-ui-build/test/test.passed

Tags: android, android-source

I sync the latest code, but get fallowing build fail.

Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4 (19E287)

FAILED: out/soong/.primary/soong-ui-build/test/test.passed

out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/gotestrunner -p ./build/soong/ui/build -f out/soong/.primary/soong-ui-build/test/test.passed -- out/soong/.primary/soong-ui-build/test/test -test.short

--- FAIL: TestDumpRBEMetricsErrors (0.33s)
--- FAIL: TestDumpRBEMetricsErrors/failed_to_copy_metrics_file (0.01s)
rbe_test.go:111: got "rbe bootstrap with shutdown failed with: fork/exec /Volumes/android/android/out/soong/.temp/TestDumpRBEMetricsErrors_failed_to_copy_metrics_file418957930/001/bootstrap: exec format error\n\n", want "failed to copy" to be contained in error
FAIL

Answer (score 0):

https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/build/soong/+/1384901

Add newline to each generated bash script in rbe_test.go.

"exec format error" showed up on Mac when running the rbe_test.go.
The generated bash scripts did not have a newline at the end of
the file.

Bug: b/162600461
Fixes: b/162600461

Test: "m blueprint_tools" on Android Mac builder.
Change-Id: I425fa5f428733b6569c3fcdaa312023f9761d020